# Does armclang/armcc provide options for copy-elision?

Tags: arm, armcc, armclang

I have read some documents regarding on gcc on copy-elision and they provide options "-fno-elide-constructors" to disable copy-elision. I am wondering if arm supports this as well.
I could not find any answer on arm user guide and reference guide...

Answer (score 0):

`armclang` is built on top of `Clang` and most `Clang` command-line options are also ported to `armclang`. Since `-fno-elide-constructors` is available in `Clang`, I think `armclang` also support it.